# Merge two dataframe if col values are in within a group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would need help in order to merge two dataframe but only when some values are shared between them.

So for instance I have 2 dataframes :

**df1**

```
Values1           Values2     COL3
Canis_lupus:E     YP_0E9E98E  12
Canis_lupus:o     YP_0E9E98E  89
Canis_lupus:E     YP_5555555  19
Homo_sapiens:1    YP_666666   23
Homo_sapiens:2    YP_5555555  32
Cattus_cattus:56e AXXADFAF    5
Cattus_cattus:56e YOPD        90
```

**df2**

```
Groups Values
G1     Canis_lupus:E
G1     Canis_lupus:o
G1     YP_0E9E98E
G2     YP_5555555
G2     YP_666666
G2     Homo_sapiens:1
G2     Homo_sapiens:2
G3     Cattus_cattus:56e
G3     AXXADFAF
G3     AGGAHAT
```

and the idea is to merge `df2` in `df1` by adding the `df2['Groups']` where there is the same `df2['Values']` and `df1['Values1']` and only if `df1['Values2']` is within the group in `df2`.

So for instance in df2 `G1` :

`Canis_lupus:E` and `Canis_lupus:o` are present in `df1` and only `YP_0E9E98E` in within `G1` in `df2`.

so I get :

**New_df**

```
Groups Values1        Values2     COL3 
G1     Canis_lupus:E  YP_0E9E98E  12
G1     Canis_lupus:o  YP_0E9E98E  89
```

Fro the all example the expected outpout would be :

```
   Groups  Values1           Values2     COL3
   G1      Canis_lupus:E     YP_0E9E98E  12
   G1      Canis_lupus:o     YP_0E9E98E  89
   G2      Homo_sapiens:1    YP_666666   23
   G2      Homo_sapiens:2    YP_5555555  32
   G3      Cattus_cattus:56e AXXADFAF    5
```

Does someone have an idea using pandas ? thanks a lot

here are the data in dic format :

**df1:**

```
{'Values1': {0: 'Canis_lupus:E', 1: 'Canis_lupus:o', 2: 'Canis_lupus:E', 3: 'Homo_sapiens:1', 4: 'Homo_sapiens:2', 5: 'Cattus_cattus:56e', 6: 'Cattus_cattus:56e'}, 'Values2': {0: 'YP_0E9E98E', 1: 'YP_0E9E98E', 2: 'YP_5555555', 3: 'YP_666666', 4: 'YP_5555555', 5: 'AXXADFAF', 6: 'YOPD'}, ' COL3': {0: 12, 1: 89, 2: 19, 3: 23, 4: 32, 5: 5, 6: 90}}

df2 : 

{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G2', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G2', 6: 'G2', 7: 'G3', 8: 'G3', 9: 'G3'}, 'Values': {0: 'Canis_lupus:E', 1: 'Canis_lupus:o', 2: 'YP_0E9E98E', 3: 'YP_5555555', 4: 'YP_666666', 5: 'Homo_sapiens:1', 6: 'Homo_sapiens:2', 7: 'Cattus_cattus:56e', 8: 'AXXADFAF', 9: 'AGGAHAT'}}
```

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='Values1', right_on='Values')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do an inner join. Code below:

```
df=pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='Values1', right_on='Values').drop_duplicates(subset='Values1')
```